# Greedy Promise resolve for a semantic parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, promise

I'm trying to create a semantic parser, that parses elements and try to resolve a type for each element (types are also elements itself).
I tried to create the following minimal working example to specify my problem:

```js
// Elements are defined with a name and an typeID:
class Element{
    name = "";
    typeID = "";
    type = null;

    waitPromise = null;

    constructor(name, typeID){
        this.name = name;
        this.typeID = typeID;
    }
}

// some generic event listener for resolving/waiting for types
class Events{
    waitForTypes =  {};

    waitForType(typeName, cb){
        if(!this.waitForTypes[typeName]){
            this.waitForTypes[typeName] = [];
        }
        this.waitForTypes[typeName].push(cb);
    }
    triggerTypeFound(typeName){
        if(this.waitForTypes[typeName] && this.waitForTypes[typeName].length > 0){
            for(let cb of this.waitForTypes[typeName]){
                cb()
            }
            delete this.waitForTypes[typeName]
        }
    }
}


// the parser itself
class Parser extends Events{
    registredTypes = [];
    typePromises = [];

    resolveType(element){
        console.log("resolve type: "+ element.name)
        this.registredTypes[element.name] = element;
        this.triggerTypeFound(element.name)
    }

    async getType(typeId){
        if(this.registredTypes[typeId]){
            return Promise.resolve(this.registredTypes[typeId]);
        } else {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.waitForType(typeId, () => {
                    resolve(this.registredTypes[typeId])
                })
            });
        }
    }

    parseElement(element){
        console.log("parse Element " + element.name);
        this.resolveType(element);

         // getType needs to be unblocking, because it might never finish
        let typePromise = this.getType(element.typeID).then(type => {
            console.log("set Type for " + element.name);
            element.type = type
        });
        this.typePromises.push(typePromise)
    }

    parseElements(elements){
        for(let element of elements){
            this.parseElement(element);
        }
        console.log("parsing finished", this.waitForTypes);
    }
}

let elements = [
    new Element("A", "B"), // Element "A" with the Type "B"
    new Element("B", "B"), // Element "B" with the Type "B"
    new Element("C", "B"), // Element "C" with the Type "B"
];
let parser = new Parser()
parser.parseElements(elements)

Promise.all(parser.typePromises).then(() => {
    console.log("all types are resolved");
})
```

If you execute the above script you will see that all elements are parsed and all types are registered within the parser.
If you parse `Element("A", "B")` the Element `A` is parsed → type `A` is registered. The Element `A` has the Type `B`, which is not a registered type, so the parser is waiting for it to resolve.
At the end all elements are parsed and all types could be resolved so `all types are resolved` is printed.

So my actual Problem is: if not all types could be resolved I want to trigger a message `parsing finished, not all types are resolved`. But `set Type ..` is triggered after `parsing finished`. The Promises for `getType` are added at the end of the event loop.

Is there a way to resolve them with higher priority ? Or is the architecture of the parser badly designed ?

The parser might never resolve all types so:

```js
let elements = [
    new Element("A", "B")
];
let parser = new Parser()
parser.parseElements(elements)
```

should trigger a message that the parser is finished but was not able to resolve everything.

Comment: I don't see any async operations going on here. Why are you using promises?

Comment: The `getType` method doesn't know if the type is already registered, so it returns a promise, that is resolved as soon as the type is registered. In the real parser the state is also saved over a longer time and the user can add when ever he wants. what would be a better solution for `getType` without the promise ?

Comment: Don't use promises, just register callbacks for when a type is defined, and run their actions (only `element.type = type`?) synchronously as soon as possible. At the end of your parsing, you can even iterate through the leftover registrations.

Comment: Or even simpler, just build a multi-stage parser, that first reads all elements and creates types from them, then assigns types to all the elements after all types are known.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'll try to remove the promises, even so I'm not sure if that is possible, since this is a very simplified example. Maybe I can rephrase the problem.

Comment: A multi-stage parser is not possible, because the parsing depends on the types and the types are nested (it's a xmi parser if someone is wondering). Even so the `parsing` part seems to be synchronous, it can be paused if the parent type is not resolved.